# What are these two insects (or at least one of them)?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, taxonomy

I need to catch and identify insects for my biology project, but I cant identify those two bugs.

Can I get the genus and the species (or it can be just general name of what this type of bug is called?)

They were found in Chicago suburban area.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add a short description for their morphology is not very clear to me,especially the second one? Has it got wings?

Comment: This question should be splitted, because now you cannot except both right answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I the first insect is a cricket, female Fall Field Cricket,*Gryllus pennsylvanicus*.

> It is widespread across much of North America.They are  often found around areas of human habitation.
>
> The the coloration ranges from dark black to dark brown, although some specimens show a slight reddish tint. The black antennae tend to be longer than the body span of the species.

It is a female because it has a long blackish brown ovipositor.

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

References:

1. Wikipedia
2. [pbase.com](http://www.pbase.com/markb249/us_orthops)
3. bugguide

Comment: Thanks! I also found the second insect and answered in another answer. I gave you best still..

Answer (score 10):

After tiring hours of research of not knowing what even is the second bug's order I've finally found the second bug as other part of the answer.

The second bug is Slender meadow katydid, *Conocephalus fasciatus* from order Orthoptera, also a female.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The green abdominal projection is its ovipositor.